# Is there any way to do preprocessing when linking static libraries?

Tags: c, static-libraries

I have some source files `.c`; they are actually a library provided by others. When I build my program to use this library, I have to compile these files again. I can't to compile the files into a static library because the sources contain some preprocessor flags. I have to generate many static libraries with different composition of preprocessor flags.

So, is there any technique that I can build a static library, and select what preprocessor flags should be used when linking with this library?

Comment: As Matteo said, with the source code as it stands, you have to build separate libraries, whether static or shared, for each combination of preprocessor flags.  Why do you so often need different sets of preprocessor flags?  Maybe the library should be more nearly configurable at runtime instead of being configured solely at compile time.  Then you could have a single library and would be able to use that in all your programs.

Comment: Actually, I'm an embedded guy. I have to choose preprocessor flags when I compile for different processor. What I have to do is change `-D` options in `gcc` command-line flags then compile the sources again. It actually take some time. So I wander a good way to save compiling time.

Comment: If you need different flags for different processors, there's no way to avoid recompiling the code.  The code compiled for one processor type won't work on others — unless the processors are compatible like the Intel family are.  So you'd have to rebuild the library pretty much regardless.

Comment: The processors are in a family. They are all same except some little difference. What I am considering is to build a static library for each of composition of preprocessor flags, then combine all library into one big library. I can specify which sub-library should be used by specifying some flags to linker when linking the big library. Can this come true?

Comment: Probably not. There isn't likely to be a good way to do it (if there's a way at all, which I seriously doubt).  If you can code to the common core code of the processors, then it would be possible to use the lowest common denominator code for all.  If you want to tune to each processor, you need to compile to each processor, and that has to be done before link time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope; a static library is a collection of object modules, a stage of compilation where it's to late to change anything but the linking options.

If you need to have different build options for each project just build the library together with the project that needs it; static libraries are rarely worth the effort anyway.

Comment: You mean I should build a static library for each composition of preprocessor flags. Then build a big library than contains all of them? But how could I link the specific library?

Comment: No I mean that in such a situation you should ditch static libraries and just build your dependency along with each project of yours.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't.  You would need the source code.  There are three basic steps in c compiling to go from source to executable.

Source->Preprocessor->Compilation into Object Files->Linking->Executable

The static libraries are kind of like the object files.  They have already been compiled and preprocessed before that.  Static libraries are used by the linker to make the final executable.

Comment: I understand what you said. Just I want to find is there any weird way to break the rule.